# How do I get certain data within a text file using arrays?

Tags: java, text

I have a text file (Items.txt) that has the following data: date, name, description and price and its formatted like so:

```
31/10/2018, Food, Hamburger, 10.00
31/10/2018, Clothes, Hoodie, 50.00
1/11/2018, Games, Controller, 150.00
1/11/2018, Food, Chips, 5.00
```

How would I get the total amount of the the food only? Here is the snippet I have worked so far:

```
public static double totalFoodExpense(byte choiceCode, byte[] expenseChoiceCode, double[]totalExpense) throws  IOException{
    double total =0;
    double amount = 0;
    String expense= "";
    xpenseCode = 0;
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner read = new Scanner(new File("Items.txt"));
    System.out.println("Enter the expense code to determine the total amount that you have spent on");
    System.out.println("Codes <  Food(1), Clothes(2), Games(3),  > \n Please " +
            "just enter a number");
    xpenseCode = Byte.parseByte(kb.nextLine());
    while (read.hasNextLine()){
        String oneLine = read.nextLine();
        String[] parts = oneLine.split(",");
        if(xpenseCode == 1){
           //Nothing yet

        }
    }

    return total;
}
```

The user would enter a number( 1 for Food, 2 for clothes, and 3 for games) to determine the total amount of that certain item. So an expected output would look like this:

```
Enter the expense code to determine the total amount that you have spent on
Codes <  Food(1), Clothes(2), Games(3), > Please just enter a number: 
1 <--user input 
The total expense of Food is 15.00
```

Comment: You test whether the item in the line matches the entered expense code, and if so, add the cost.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? All you have to do is to check if the second element of `parts` is the type you want (`Food` in this case), and if it is then add the price to some local variable storing total food expenses.

Comment: Why  `Byte.parseByte()`?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out.

```
public static double totalTuitionExpense() throws  IOException{
    double total =0;
    double amount = 0;
    String expense= "";
    byte xpenseCode = 0;
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner read = new Scanner(new File("items.txt"));

    System.out.print("Enter 1 for Food: ");
    try{
    xpenseCode = Byte.parseByte(kb.nextLine());
    double sum = 0.0;
    while (read.hasNextLine()){
        String oneLine = read.nextLine();
        String[] parts = oneLine.split(",");
        amount = Double.parseDouble(parts[3]);
        expense = parts[1];
        if(xpenseCode == 1){
                if (expense.compareToIgnoreCase("tuition")==0) {
                    sum += amount;
                }
            }
        }
    System.out.printf("The total expense of Food is %.2f%n", sum);}
    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
        return total;
    }
```